# JS Regex- find a substring contains special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, substring, special-characters, capture-group

Can you please help me to understand how to do the following?

I'm having a strings (3 formats for this string):

1. "Section_1: hello & goodbye | section_2: kuku"
2. "Section_1: hello & goodbye & hola | section_2: kuku"
3. "Section_1: hello | section_2: kuku"

I want the get the result:

1. Group section_1: "hello & goodbye",
   Group section_2: "kuku"
2. Group section_1: "hello & goodbye & hola",
   Group section_2: "kuku"
3. Group section_1: "hello",
   Group section_2: "kuku"

Now I have the regex (but it's not working for me because of the '&'):

```
Section_1:\s*(?<section_1>\w+)(\s*\|\s*(Section_2:(\s*(?<section_2>.*))?)?)?
```

Note: the regex is capturing 2 groups- "section_1" and "section_2"

The question is- how can I read sub string the can contains zero or more from " & {word}"

Thanks in advance

Comment: If these are the three formats, then why are you creating optional groupings? Do you have more possible formats by any chance? Also, `\w+` matches word-characters. The sections 1 parts contain spaces and ampersands (thus fail currently). Do you wish to check this specific pattern too? For example [`^section_1:\s*(?<section_1>[a-z]+(?:\s+&\s[a-z]+)*)\s*\|\s*section_2:\s*(?<section_2>[a-z]+(?:\s+&\s[a-z]+)*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/W2yd57/1) may validate the entire input's pattern, but could be simplified depending if you don't need to be this specific.

Comment: try with `(?<section>[Ss]ection_\d):\s*(?<content>[^|\n\r]+)( \||\n\r?|$)`

Comment: @JvdV, hey, thanks for your comment.
I don't have only 3 formats, I gave an example, let me make it more clear.
The string- "word1 & word2 & ......" is actually a sub string contains words concat with ' & ', and I don't really understand how to handle with this case that the string can contains zero or more concats with ' & '

Comment: @MayAsk, so the combination acts like a delimiter. That's fine. Did you read through my entire comment and clicked the link?

Comment: @JvdV Hey, Your solutions works!!! thanks!!!
can you please explain why you put (?:\s+&\s\w+)*) as a non-capturing group?

Comment: Sure, I'll put it down in an aswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments we established that the ' & '- combination acts as a delimiter between words. There are probably a ton of ways to write a pattern to capture these substrings, but to me these can be grouped into extensive or simple. Depending if you need to validate the input more thoroughly you could use:

```
^section_1:\s*(?<section_1>[a-z]+(?:\s&\s[a-z]+)*)\s*\|\s*section_2:\s*(?<section_2>[a-z]+(?:\s&\s[a-z]+)*)$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DJUFq/1). The pattern means:

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `section_1:\s*` - Match 'Section_1:' literally followed by 0+ whitespace characters;
- `(?<section_1>[a-z]+(?:\s+&\s[a-z]+)*)` - A named capture group to catch `[a-z]+` as 1+ upper/lower letters (case-insensitive flag), followed by a nested non-capture group matching 0+ times the pattern `(?:\s&\s[a-z]+)*` to test for any delimiter as per above followed by another word;
- `\s*\|\s*section_2:\s*` - Match whitespace characters, a literal pipe-symbol and literally 'Section_2:' upto;
- `(?<section_2>[a-z]+(?:\s&\s[a-z]+)*)` - A 2nd named capture group to match the same pattern as the above named capture group;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

---

**Note**: As mentioned, there are a ton of differnt pattern one could use depending on how specific you need to be about validating input. For example: [`\s*(?<section_1>[^:|]+?)\s*\|\s*[^:]*:\s*(?<section_2>.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/SoLF7T/1) may also work.